# OpenID registration

Tags: php, zend-framework, openid

Who to create openid registration as on this site?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using OpenID with Zend Framework.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968607/using-openid-with-zend-framework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CommunityID at http://source.keyboard-monkeys.org/projects/show/communityid will do what you are asking...

Answer (score 0):

- http://www.slideshare.net/kuchmuch/implementing-openid
- http://devzone.zend.com/article/3581

### First Steps

The first thing you'll need, if you're going to begin accepting OpenIDs on your Web site, is a sign-in form. Here's the code:

```
<form method="post">
      Sign in with your OpenID: <br/>
      <input type="text" name="id" size="30" />
      <br />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" />
</form>
```

...

That should get you started.

Comment: it's authorization? but i need registration...then user come to my site, and hi don't have openid, i redirect he to https://www.myopenid.com/. Then user registration on https://www.myopenid.com/ he back (redirect) to my site with openid