# Common parameter to retrieve email address from OpenID provider

Tags: php, openid

In my site, I am using authentication based on OpenID. I am requesting 'email address' from the OpenID provider. The problem is each provider is sending the email address in their own parameter in GET response after authentication.
I am listing down three of what I have seen

**StackExchange**

> openid_alias3_value_alias1

**Yahoo!**

> openid_ax_value_email

**Google**

> openid_ext1_value_email

It is difficult (and not standard) to write separate lines of code for each OpenID provider.
Is there a standard for this?

**(added a bug : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106922/stackexchange-openid-parameter-for-email-should-be-openid-ax-value-email)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there's no identifier like `openid.email` defined in the [Positive Assertions](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#positive_assertions) section of the OpenID Auth 2.0 specs, I'd say: *no, there is no such standard*.

OpenID supports [extensions](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#extensions) to carry extra data like `email`, but it's completely up to the OpenID provider which data to reveal (if any at all), what identifiers to use and where to place them in their extension namespace hierarchy.

Comment: lets hope most common parameters like email will be standardized in the future versions of OpenID.